# Determine if a .lnk points to a metro app

Tags: winapi, microsoft-metro, lnk

How to determine by .lnk (or its target), whether it points to a metro (Windows 8) application?

For instance, the shop link shortcut points to `%windir%\WinStore\WinStore.htm`. How should I know, that it's not an ordinal page, but a metro style app?

Comment: That is not a metro style app.  That a web page can use the ms-appx protocol handler is not something you can detect from a shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, how reliable the solution is, but in both start menu folders (all users and current user) all metro apps lnk files are system+archive+readonly. And the others are not. Kinda hack, but works so far. Not sure, what to do with lnk in any other folders.